# Why is foreach and %dopar% (doParallel package) slower than a while loop for iteration?

Tags: r, performance, foreach, while-loop, iterator

Using a **while loop** for the code below finishes in about 20 seconds. Using **foreach** and **%dopar%** without clusters is about 25 seconds and with clusters about 28 seconds.

I'm looking for clarification since I've read [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963808/foreach-dopar-slower-than-for-loop) that small task can be slower with parallel-processing, but when I increase the +/- for the numbers in **iproduct** the parallel-processing is still slower.

Is this because;

1. I'm using **iproduct** and instead should use a different iterator or
2. The amount of data being iterated by **iproduct** needs to be much much bigger for parallelizing makes sense or
3. The amount of computation in the **while loop** is a small task so parallelizing won't ever make it faster.

Any help on getting my code to run faster would be great.

My final data won't be huge since I am only keep what makes it through the conditional **if** statement, but I want to iterate over more numbers than what I currently have for p1&2 and r0-2.

Here is the **while loop** code

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
p1<-2
p2<-2
r0<-25
r1<-4
r2<-0

TB<-c()
iter_count <- ihasNext(iproduct(ani1=(p1-2):(p1+2), ani2=(p2-2):(p2+2),
                      fd0=(r0-6):(r0+6), fd1=(r1-4):(r1+6), fd2=(r2):(r2+6)))

while( hasNext(iter_count) ) {
  ne <- nextElem(iter_count)
  aniprev <- sum(ne$ani1,ne$ani2)
  SRFD <- sum(ne$fd1,(2*ne$fd2))
  totalSRFD <- sum(ne$fd0,ne$fd1,ne$fd2)
  manhattan_dist<-sum(abs(p1-ne$ani1),abs(p2-ne$ani2),
                      abs(r0-ne$fd0),abs(r1-ne$fd1),abs(r2-ne$fd2))
  
  if(manhattan_dist <=5 & aniprev == SRFD & totalSRFD == 29)
  {ani<-cbind(ne$ani1, ne$ani2, ne$fd0,
               ne$fd1, ne$fd2, manhattan_dist)
  TB=rbind(TB,ani)}
}
nodup2 <- TB[!duplicated(t(apply(TB, 1, sort))), ]

end_time <- Sys.time()

end_time - start_time
```

And here is the **foreach** and **%dopar%** parallel equivalent

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
p1<-2
p2<-2
r0<-25
r1<-4
r2<-0

iter_count <- iproduct(ani1=(p1-2):(p1+2), ani2=(p2-2):(p2+2),
               fd0=(r0-6):(r0+6), fd1=(r1-4):(r1+6), fd2=(r2):(r2+6))

dc <- detectCores()-1
registerDoParallel(dc)

res <- foreach(i=iter_count, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
aniprev <- sum(i$ani1,i$ani2)
SRFD <- sum(i$fd1,(2*i$fd2))
totalSRFD <- sum(i$fd0,i$fd1,i$fd2)
manhattan_dist<-sum(abs(p1-i$ani1),abs(p2-i$ani2),
                    abs(r0-i$fd0),abs(r1-i$fd1),abs(r2-i$fd2))

if(manhattan_dist <=5 & aniprev == SRFD & totalSRFD == 29)
{ani<-cbind(i$ani1, i$ani2, i$fd0,
            i$fd1, i$fd2, manhattan_dist)}
}
nodup2 <- res[!duplicated(t(apply(res, 1, sort))), ]

end_time <- Sys.time()

end_time - start_time
```

Comment: Option number 3 is correct. Foreach parallelization works best if you send long tasks to each separate process. You are sending many tiny calculations to every processor core, which causes a lot of overhead from the parallel backend.

Comment: JadaLovelace, thank you!  Do you think that using 'expand.grid' and 'isplitRow' to send chunks of data to be parallel processed as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254476/combinatorial-iterator-like-expand-grid) would speed up the processing time? As I increase the original vector (p's and r's) I know it will start taking hours to days to get results.

Comment: yes, i'm pretty sure it will. i have never worked with iterator objects before, but i'll try to get an example running with the code you posted. From a technical perspective, it only makes sense to parallelize your data in as many chunks as you have cores (include hyperthreaded cores!). So if you have 4 cores available, the fastest would be to split your data in 4 chunks. Splitting into more chunks than you have cores available doesn't help.

Comment: I realized that the answer I linked to in my comment above won't work. They split the data into chunks before **expand.grid** and doing that will not give all the combinations of my example. Using **expand.grid** instead of **iproduct/ihasNext** give me 25,025 results. Splitting up the r's (r0=19:25, r1=0:5, r2=0:3) gave 4,200 results and (r0=26:31, r1=6:10, r2=4:6) gave 2,250 results for a total of 6,450. The issue is **iproduct** gives results one at a time and **expand.grid** gives it all at once. If parallel processing could be useful in this situation I would need something in between.

Comment: I also realized that I would not have to write a function for apply since the function **subset** in R would give me the data with the conditions I set. Maybe putting **expand.grid** inside a function that splits the data would work. If not, I'll post another question. Thank you again, JadaLovelace.